# How to knockout a shape using the top layer in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, shapes

I have three layers, and want to use the top layer to knockout the shape from the underline layers so that it is transparent. Don't I use the shape builder tool or is there another way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "underline" layers. Did you mean underlying layers?

Answer (score 0):

Put the layers inside a 4th layer, select the layers appearance with the sphere next to the appaearnce name. Make that layer a transparency knockout group. Select the topmost sublayers appearance and make it transparent. The downside is that all the other transparencies now also knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Set the transparency of the topmost object to 0% > group all three objects > go to TRANSPARENCY PANEL > click on KNOCKOUT GROUP.

Comment: Sorry, that is, "Set the transparency of the topmost OBJECT to 0%..."

Comment: could you add some screenshots showing how this works?